# multi client can not upload file at same time in node.js

Tags: node.js, concurrency, upload, express

am using express.js and uploadify to upload large file to node server, everything works fine except when more than one user login and try to upload file at same time, well it still works but it seems that the server can only upload one file at a time, so the user have to wait until the other user finish their uploading, this is so unacceptable.

here is server side code

```
exports.upload = function(req, res,next){
    // console.log( req.body);
    // console.log(req.files);
    var tmp_path = req.files.product_video.path;
    var target_path = 'F:/shopping/shop/' +req.body.shop_id+'/'+ req.files.product_video.name;

    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    exec("C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i shop/"+ req.body.shop_id+ '/' + req.files.product_video.name  + " -ss 00:01:00.00 -r 1 -an -vframes 1 -s 250x150 -f mjpeg shop/"+ req.body.shop_id+ '/'  + req.files.product_video.name  + "_thumbnail.jpg", function(err){

                        var data = {
                            'thum_src':'shop/'+ req.body.shop_id+ '/'  + req.files.product_video.name  + "_thumbnail.jpg",
                            'video_name':req.files.product_video.name,
                        }
                        res.send(data);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });
};
```

here is front end code

```
 $('#input_product_video').uploadify({
        'formData':{'shop_id':$('#shop_id').val()},
        'buttonText'    : 'add',
        'fileSizeLimit' : '100MB',
        'fileObjName' : 'product_video',
        'uploader'    : '/uploads',
        'swf'         :'/public/javascripts/lib/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'onUploadSuccess':function(file,data){
             console.log(file);
             console.log(JSON.parse(data));
             console.log(response);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the `fs.unlink` call because `fs.rename` is going to move the file to the correct path, not copy it, so if `fs.rename` succeeds, the temporary file will already be gone. Remove the whole `fs.unlink` block, which doesn't check for an error anyway. Then you need to make sure in every possible path through the code, you are either calling `next(err)` with an error or calling `res.send`. It looks like there are code paths in here where you will not respond and will just let the request time out. Make those changes and see if that gets it working.